# How do I create a specific number of subfolders, that depends on the number of objects in an image file, using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a script that crops individual objects within an image file, and I want to create a subfolder for each individual cropped image.

This program was originally created in Matlab. This is the code:

```
tmgrph_cropDir = [writeParent_datDir '\Tomography Crops\ '  ];   %- Set path to new folder
mkdir(tmgrph_cropDir);      % - Create new folder (write directory)

%- Create subfolders for each object

 for k = 1 : length(measurements):                  
     obj_num = ["\ " sprintf("obj%03d",k)];      %- Set object folder
     tmgrphObj_cropDir = [tmgrph_cropDir obj_num];      % - Set object full path
     mkdir(tmgrphObj_cropDir);      %- Create object write directories

 end
```

I am trying to convert this to Python. Here is what I have so far:

```
 dir_name = '\Tomography Crop\ '
 tmgrph_cropDir = os.path.join(writeParent_datDir, dir_name)
 os.mkdir(tmgrph_cropDir)

 #ROI_number - This is the number of cropped objects in the image 

 k=0
 for k in ROI_number:
      obj_num = '/ Obj 1/ '
      tmgrphObj_cropDir = os.path.append(tmgrph_datDir, obj_num)
      os.mkdir(tmgrphObj_cropDir)
 end
```

I get an error on the Python code.

AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'append'

Also, how would I get it to name each file according to the object. So 'obj 1', 'obj 2', 'obj 3' etc. Instead of just creating ROI_number number of subfolders all named the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dir_name = '\Tomography Crop\ '
 tmgrph_cropDir = os.path.join(writeParent_datDir, dir_name)
 os.mkdir(tmgrph_cropDir)

 #ROI_number - This is the number of cropped objects in the image 

 k=0
 for k in ROI_number:
      obj_num = '/ Obj 1/ '
      tmgrphObj_cropDir = os.path.join(tmgrph_datDir, obj_num)
      os.mkdir(tmgrphObj_cropDir)
```

os.path doesn't have an append method, you should use join()